# React Native opening a local file from webview

Tags: webview, react-native

After downloading a PDF or any other type of file, I'm having trouble opening it from a webview. Basically, I would like to be able to display a href pointed to the local file, e.g. `<a href="/data/users/0/com.myapp/files/some.pdf"></a>` - and then prompt the user to open it in an external application. Currently it seems to hang / not recognize the downloaded file.

The data in this file is currently base64 encoded. Can I send this binary data to an external app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to intercept the url using `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest` and use the `Linking` native module provided by react-native. More info here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html#opening-external-links